# How to manage Validation vs raw values in Objection.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I have this model in Objection.js:

```
class UserAccess extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'user_access'
    }

    static get jsonSchema() {
        return {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
                id: {
                    type: 'integer'
                },
                user_id: {
                    type: 'integer'
                }
                timestamp: {
                    type: 'string',
                    format: 'date-time'
                },
            },
            additionalProperties: false
        }
    }

    $beforeInsert() {
        this.timestamp = this.$knex().raw('now()')
    }

    static async insert(data) {
        const result = await this.query().insert(data)
        return result.id
    }
```

I need to insert the **database time** in `timestamp` column. When Objection executes the validation, the value of `timestamp` is an intance of Raw Knex Function:

```
Raw {
  client:
   Client_MySQL2 {
     config: { client: 'mysql2', connection: [Object] },
     connectionSettings:
      { user: '',
        password: '',
        host: '',
        database: '' },
     driver:
      { createConnection: [Function],
        connect: [Function],

// continues
```

So when validation is executed, an error is returned, since it isnt a string:

```
Validation error: "timestamp" should be a string
```

Is there any way to use the **database time** and **keep the validation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chain the query builder with a ".then()" to get the query result or use async/await. This might work:

```
async $beforeInsert() {
    this.timestamp = await this.$knex().raw('now()')
}
```

or:

```
$beforeInsert() {
   this.timestamp = this.$knex().raw('now()').then(function(result) {
      console.log(result)
   })
}
```

https://knexjs.org/#Interfaces

Comment: Thanks! But I dont understand why `knex().raw()` doesnt return an unsolved promise instead in my example

Comment: Anyway, `beforeInsert` is executed after validation. I have just realized my example doesnt fit my problem...